# Google analytics new version has no summary?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to understand this new version of Google analytics and I'm really puzzled. One of biggest assets (to me at least) was that I was able to see with a glance how my sites are doing. In the old version, this was easy as cake, but with new version, I'm stumped - how could they replace something so useful with ... NOTHING???

When I logged into old version I got this:

[image]

And on new version I get this, which is nothing...

[image]

Is there any reasoning behind this or is it just a fluke? If this new version becomes only version, I'll be forced to find my analytics happiness somewhere else ...

Comment: Voting to close as all you're really going to get here is speculation. But for the little it's worth, here's a [support thread](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/analytics/tkQ9nFsmpPY/QFSo7gpDjPcJ) where someone says Google told them it's definitely gone and "might" come back but with no timeframe about. I'd suggest you explore external clients that might be able to present the data in the way you want in the meantime, and maybe post a feature request to add your support for its return.

Comment: Close is fine with me, I couldn't find the link you supplied. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add, there is a link at the bottom of the page to report issues, I suggest using that (which I have done for other issues like the mediocre dashboard). Hopefully they are getting enough complaints about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick with the old interface. Their new interface is really bad, they are making a bunch of new and worse interface across their products. Like the new gmail interface, replacing text buttons with icons.